# HTML Select Scroll Bar Not Functioning Correctly in Chrome 32

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

**UPDATE: Now fixed for Version 32.0.1700.102 m. Update your version of Chrome if you haven't already.**

So as many of you may or may not know, Chrome just recently auto-updated from version 31.0 to 32.0 yesterday or today.

For some reason, the scroll bars in HTML select elements do not scroll if you try to drag them with your mouse, nor do they scroll if you click in the scroll area to move it up or down. The only way you can get it to move is by using your mouse wheel or keyboard.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6eSQY/2/

I have seen other select elements that DO scroll correct, but in most cases that I've seen out on the web, they behave like the JSFiddle I included above.

Any thoughts as to what I can do to rectify the problem in my web apps?

Comment: Get hired by the Chrome team? Submit a bug to chromium? There's not much you can do to fix it since it's a browser bug.

Comment: FYI it's still "broken" in Chrome 33.0.1750.29 beta

Comment: Chrome get some problem with scroll bar recently as for resized window too. Hope dev team will  fix it soon

Comment: @tkone I used the `Report an issue` under the Chrome >> Tools menu, but how come I feel like that just goes into some DB that nobody checks? (if it even does go into a DB)

Comment: @FastTrack. I'm sure someone checks those at some point during some time period. Chromium is open source -- you could always write some C++ and fix it there yourself but like, unless you want to change all your `<select>` elements to be crazy nested `<div>` tags there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Well this just plain sucks...

Comment: Confirmed bug, works fine in `Chrome 31`, just upgraded to `32`, and they have redesigned it to fade in, and the scrollbar is broken when you try and drag it, although the `mouse wheel` scroll works fine. Possibly related to this? http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57617308-93/chrome-users-mad-at-google-for-switching-up-scroll-controls/

Comment: @NickR well good to know it's confirmed and they are working on a resolution... I expect better out of Google, maybe I'm just naive...

Comment: The example works for me in 32.0.1700.76.

Comment: @Douglas I'm using the same version and it doesn't work for me and a lot of other people. Are you using Windows 7?

Comment: @FastTrack no, that was Win8.0, but yes, it is broken on a different Win7 machine.

Comment: Since this is closed, see my answer on SuperUser. It's an easy fix, that only affects Chrome. http://superuser.com/a/704737/30941

Comment: It is just incredible how a bug like this passes through the test phase. I mean.. come on. Very very very, if nog.. VERY bad from the dev team of Google Chromium

Comment: @Nique Agreed! I'm amazed that a company like Google could have a dev team that allows such an obvious bug slip through the cracks

Comment: @FastTrack I know why it slips through: Unit Tests instead of real-life tests. In the first place i really hate to write unit tests (because making these tests takes as long as just testing it yourself) but also simple bugs as these are not 'unit tested' and therefore not tested at all, while if you test 'old school' you will notice this bug right away :). Google man.. omg; Use both :).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue has been [reported](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334522) but doesn't look like there is a fix yet from Google.

The only solutions that seem to be available at this point are:

1. Uncheck "Use visual styles on windows and buttons" (Right-click Computer > Advanced tab > Performance settings > Visual Effects tab...[see here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/127339-visual-styles-windows-buttons-turn-off.html)) and the select boxes will act as normal.
2. Use a chrome extension like [Rescroller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rescroller/ddehdnnhjimbggeeenghijehnpakijod/related).
3. Use your mouse-wheel to scroll.
4. Use down/up arrows to scroll.

**UPDATE: Now fixed for Version 32.0.1700.102 m**. Update your version of Chrome if you haven't already.

Comment: A full functional workaround is to; Go to start and type “Theme”, Click “Change the Theme” and Select “Windows 7 Basic”.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Version 32.0.1700.102 m

Comment: Chrome can still prevent scrolling down the page, on the latest version, so it still has scrollbar bugs. Better to use Firefox.

Comment: Just to add info, there are still problems ( for me ) with Chrome scrollbar ( Chrome ver 35.0.1916.153 m )